# How can I use Lenses to perform read-only monadic operation over a sequence held in some state?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

My data structure looks more or less like this (simplified for the purpose of the question)

```
data GameObject = GameObject { _num :: Int }
data Game = Game { _objects :: [GameObject] }
```

I use `makeLenses` to generate the accessors for both of those. Thus, I am able to do operations *en masse* like this:

```
-- loop :: MonadState with Game inside
loop = objects.traversed.num += 1
```

And this is great.

---

However, I can't find a way to do an equivalent of this (printing every `num`):

```
game <- get
let objects = _objects game
let objectNums = map _num objects
mapM_ print objectNums
```

I have tried things like

```
uses (objects.traversed.num) >>= mapM_ print
```

but the only way I see to use `traversed` with some state like that involves using monoids, and I don't want to combine the fields; I want to *run a monadic action over a part of every element in the elements from some sequence that resides in my state*.

So, is this possible using some provided Lens function or do I have to write that myself, somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
mapMOf_ (objects . traversed . num) print
```

or if you want to apply that to the state of a state monad,

```
get >>= mapMOf_ (objects . traversed . num) print
```

? (Perhaps there's a more lens-like way to combine the first line with the state of a state monad. If so, I'd like to learn about it myself.)

Comment: I think you need `get >>=` in front, no? Otherwise, yes, *yes*! I was really struggling to find that. Perhaps I focused on automatic state extraction too much.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, sorry. I should have put it there. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

This solution runs an action on state viewed by a lens

```
objects . traverse . num .=>> putStrLn . ("num: " ++) . show
```

**Example:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Lens
--       (Getting, Lens', LensLike', lens, makeLenses, view, zoom)
import Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom -- (Focusing)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy -- (StateT(StateT), execStateT)

viewM :: Monad m => Getting t s t -> (t -> m a) -> StateT s m a
viewM g f = StateT $ \s -> (, s) <$> f (view g s)

viewEachM ::
     Monad m => LensLike' (Focusing m c) t s -> (s -> m c) -> StateT t m c
viewEachM g f = zoom g $ id .=> f

infix 4 .=>, .=>>

(.=>) :: Monad m => Getting t s t -> (t -> m a) -> StateT s m a
g .=> f = viewM g f

(.=>>) :: Monad m => LensLike' (Focusing m c) t s -> (s -> m c) -> StateT t m c
g .=>> f = viewEachM g f

data GameObject = GameObject
  { _num :: Int
  } deriving (Show)

data Game = Game
  { _objects :: [GameObject]
  } deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Game

makeLenses ''GameObject

defaultGame = Game {_objects = map GameObject [0 .. 3]}

action :: StateT Game IO ()
action = do
  id .=> putStrLn . ("game: " ++) . show
  objects .=> putStrLn . ("objects: " ++) . show
  objects .=> putStrLn . ("length of objects: " ++) . show . length
  -- use .=>> as alternative
  objects .=>> putStrLn . ("length of objects: " ++) . show . length
  -- if you use traverse you have to use .=>>
  objects . traverse . num .=>> putStrLn . ("num: " ++) . show

main :: IO ()
main = do
  execStateT action defaultGame
  return ()
```

**output:**

```
game: Game {_objects = [GameObject {_num = 0},GameObject {_num = 1},GameObject {_num = 2},GameObject {_num = 3}]}
objects: [GameObject {_num = 0},GameObject {_num = 1},GameObject {_num = 2},GameObject {_num = 3}]
length of objects: 4
length of objects: 4
num: 0
num: 1
num: 2
num: 3
```

---

**resolver:** lts-9.3

- lens 4.15.4
- transformers 0.5